# EWS How can I get subfolders with powershell

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices

with this code:

```
$folderview = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderView(100)
$folderview.PropertySet = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)
$folderview.PropertySet.Add([Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data.FolderSchema]::DisplayName)
$folderview.Traversal = [Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data.FolderTraversal]::Deep
$folderfindResults = $service.FindFolders([Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox, $folderview)
```

I can get all folders in a mailbox.
But how can I get only the subfolders under a particular folder?

Inbox
Process
A
...Z

I would like to get all the folders (A...Z), as well as the items of the folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the findFolder method to first find the root subfolder  and then you use that folderid to find the subfolders of it (the same as you have above) and then you need to query each child folder to get its items. To Get the initial sub-folder you can use something like the folder eg in you context you would run it like

$Subfolder = Get-FolderFromPath -MailboxName email@dom.com -FolderPath \Inbox\Process -service $service

```
    function Get-FolderFromPath {
    param (
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true)] [string]$FolderPath,
        [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = $true)] [string]$MailboxName,
        [Parameter(Position = 2, Mandatory = $true)] [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService]$service
        )
    process {
        ## Find and Bind to Folder based on Path  
        #Define the path to search should be seperated with \  
        #Bind to the MSGFolder Root  
        $psPropset = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)  
        $PidTagMessageSizeExtended = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0xe08, [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType]::Long);
        $PR_ATTACH_ON_NORMAL_MSG_COUNT = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x66B1, [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType]::Integer);
        $psPropset.Add($PidTagMessageSizeExtended)
        $psPropset.Add($PR_ATTACH_ON_NORMAL_MSG_COUNT)

        $folderid = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Root, $MailboxName)   
        $tfTargetFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service, $folderid)  
            #Split the Search path into an array  
            $fldArray = $FolderPath.Split("\") 
            if ($fldArray.Length -lt 2) {throw "No Root Folder"}
            #Loop through the Split Array and do a Search for each level of folder 
            for ($lint = 1; $lint -lt $fldArray.Length; $lint++) { 
                #Perform search based on the displayname of each folder level 
                $fvFolderView = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderView(1) 
                $fvFolderView.PropertySet = $psPropset
                $SfSearchFilter = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderSchema]::DisplayName, $fldArray[$lint]) 
                $findFolderResults = $service.FindFolders($tfTargetFolder.Id, $SfSearchFilter, $fvFolderView) 
                $tfTargetFolder = $null  
                if ($findFolderResults.TotalCount -gt 0) { 
                    foreach ($folder in $findFolderResults.Folders) { 
                        $tfTargetFolder = $folder                
                    } 
                } 
                else { 
                    Write-host ("Error Folder Not Found check path and try again") -ForegroundColor Red
                    $tfTargetFolder = $null  
                    break  
                }     
        }  

        if ($tfTargetFolder -ne $null) {
            $tfTargetFolder | Add-Member -Name "FolderPath" -Value $FolderPath -MemberType NoteProperty
            $tfTargetFolder | Add-Member -Name "Mailbox" -Value $MailboxName -MemberType NoteProperty
            $prop4Val = $null
            if ($tfTargetFolder.TryGetProperty($PidTagMessageSizeExtended, [ref]  $prop4Val)) {
                Add-Member -InputObject $tfTargetFolder -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FolderSize -Value $prop4Val
            }
            $prop5Val = $null
            if ($tfTargetFolder.TryGetProperty($PR_ATTACH_ON_NORMAL_MSG_COUNT, [ref]  $prop5Val)) {
                Add-Member -InputObject $tfTargetFolder -MemberType NoteProperty -Name PR_ATTACH_ON_NORMAL_MSG_COUNT -Value $prop5Val
            }
            return, [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]$tfTargetFolder
        
        }
        else {
            return, $null
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

What I dont understand is that the folder inbox\process has the same id like inbox\process\A

Now I like to get alle items from the folder inbox\process\A 
I use the code "$findResults = $service.FindItems($folderid , $view)"

What i need to get the folderid form folder inbox\process\A ?

Comment: Your question isn't clear the example i provided will give you the method for finding the  folder id for whatever folder path you pass in. It will return a Folder object which you can then either make the FindItems Query directly on eg $Folder.findItems($view) or you can take the FolderId from that folder